# Get value of variable inside .each() function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce

I have code below.

The code works fine, but if I uncomment the "if" statement, alert will show up as soon as I enter something to input field.

I want the "sum" value to be checked (alert shows up) only after I entered all 3 input fields.

Please help me to fix it. Thanks.

```html
<apex:inputField styleClass="Weight" value="{!EvaluationInformation__c.val1__c}" />
<apex:inputField styleClass="Weight" value="{!EvaluationInformation__c.val2__c}" />
<apex:inputField styleClass="Weight" value="{!EvaluationInformation__c.val3__c}" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input", ".Weight", function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.Weight').each(function() {
      var num = $(this).val();
      if (num != null && !isNaN(num)) {
        sum += parseFloat(num);
      } else {
        alert("Accept number only");
      }
    });

    //if (sum != 1){ // sum !=1 doesn't work
    //  alert("The total of Weight must be 1");
    //} 
  });
});
```

Comment: The code seems fine. What debugging have you done? Have you checked the console for errors? What is the value of `sum` after the loop runs? We can't really help you without knowing these details. It would also help to see the HTML output, not the visualforce template, as it's not relevant to the issue.

Comment: Working code check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0exLf8nj/) only change i have made in `if` statement you can check  `num !=""` else working fine. ( check console for result )

Comment: Alert shows up everytime i enter value to input fields that i dont want

Comment: Maybe you should change your event listener to `change`, as otherwise you will be interrupted after each time you press a key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a status flag that will tell if all inputs are valid, see my example code below.

Also, AFAIK `val()` for an `<input>` element never returns `null`, it returns "" if there is no input. This is why I used `if (num && ...` instead, which in this situation means "only proceed if `num` contains text".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".Weight", function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    var allInputsValid = true; // <-- flag variable
    $('.Weight').each(function() {
      var num = $(this).val();
      if (num && !isNaN(num)) {
        sum += parseFloat(num);
      } else {
        allInputsValid = false;
      }
    });
    if (allInputsValid) {
      console.log("All inputs have numbers.");
      if (sum != 1) {
        console.log("The total of Weight must be 1, but it is: " + sum);
      } else {
        console.log("The total of Weight is 1.");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Not all input have numbers yet.");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.Weight { width: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
#1: <input class="Weight" /> #2: <input class="Weight" /> #3: <input class="Weight" />
```

---

PS - Even then, you may have trouble making this work because of how Floating Point math works. Due to internal rounding, a sum of numbers that you would expect to be 1 will not always produce exactly 1:

```js
var x = parseFloat("0.34") + parseFloat("0.56") + parseFloat("0.10");
console.log(x);
console.log(x === 1);
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad description . I have fixed it , thank you